# How can I resolve the error "-bash: corelist: command not found"?

Tags: perl

I want to find the differences between two versions of Perl using the [`corelist`](https://metacpan.org/pod/corelist) command line utility.

I tried running the following command:

```
corelist File::Spec
```

but I got an error:

> -bash: corelist: command not found

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error suggests that corelist is not installed on your machine. If not installed, you can install it via

Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install libmodule-corelist-perl`

Centos: [Via RPM here](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/31368120/dir/centos_6/com/perl-Module-CoreList-2.18-141.el6.x86_64.rpm.html)

Once you have it installed, you can find the differences between two versions of Perl as follows:

```
corelist --diff v5.12.0 v5.24.0
```

If you have problems installing it, there is a web version of `corelist` available online to which you can refer: http://perlpunks.de/corelist It supports doing differences between Perl versions too.